# Hosting Own Nuget Package Feed in ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

I have devloped ASP.Net Project to host our own nuget package using Nuget.Server assembly.

I want to integrate the ASP Project to MVC project. The Nuget.Server assembly support MVC 4.0 version for Hosting Nuget packages.

Please suggest best solution. How to create MVC project to Host own nuget packages for customers.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [NuGet Gallery](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery). It's an MVC application with a backend which is also used for the official NuGet site. You can host it on Azure (by default) or in your own IIS. The steps involved are explained in the README. You will have to fulfill some prerequisites, such as Visual Studio 2013 and PowerShel 2.0, and after that the only things missing is to build the project, setup your IIS, create the database and change the configuration (if needed in your case).

The easiest way is to clone (or fork) the whole project and do your customizing (for example, related to the design) if needed.